# Como criar microserviços pensando em escalabilidade?

Tags: java, microsserviços, escalabilidade

Olá,

Estou construindo um microserviço que integra dados de um webservice SOAP. Para isso estou usando um agendador que uma vez por dia busca novos dados e grava na minha base mongodb. Sendo que o padrão de microserviço é ter uma base por serviço, e o meu serviço integra dados e serve esses dados para outro serviço, como vou escalar um microserviço com essas duas coisas juntas? Vou ter problema na integração dos dados, então pensei em duas soluções:

1 - Dividir meu microserviço em dois: um será responsável por integrar dados com o webservice SOAP e outro será responsável por servir esses dados, assim poderei escalar esse serviço. O problema é que isso foge do conceito de microserviço: uma base por serviço.

2 - Manter um só microserviço e para resolver o problema da escalabilidade eu poderia criar um parâmetro para dizer aos demais microserviços não executarem o agendador, deixando somente um microserviço responsável por integrar os dados. No entanto, não sei se isso funciona e me parece uma solução ruim.

Qual a melhor solução? Existe outra alternativa?